# Why does the char need to be dereferenced in this instance?

Tags: c, pointers, char, dereference

I've been doing some practice with trees in C for my undergraduate courses and I came about on very strange results.

This is the code that didn't output as expected. I have a tree with the root being the struct node * root, and the preorder function prints the data on each node on the tree.

```
struct node{
    char data;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
};

struct node* newNode(char data){
    struct node* node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return(node);
}

void preorder(struct node * root){
    //struct node * start = root;
    struct node * L;
    struct node * R;
    if(root!=NULL){
        printf("%c",root->data);
        preorder(root->left);
        preorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main(){
    struct node * root = newNode("a");
    root->left = newNode("b");
    root->right = newNode("c");
    root->left->left = newNode("d");
    root->left->right = newNode("e");
    root->right->left = newNode("f");
    root->right->right = newNode("g");
    preorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be "abdecfg", but instead the terminal is outputting a weird result, as such; https://i.imgur.com/LudpUn7.png .
I get the GCC warning "[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast", but I don't understand why.
If I use the dereference asterisk on the char inputs, the error stops, and I get the expected output, like this;

```
int main(){
    struct node * root = newNode(*"a");
    root->left = newNode(*"b");
    root->right = newNode(*"c");
    root->left->left = newNode(*"d");
    root->left->right = newNode(*"e");
    root->right->left = newNode(*"f");
    root->right->right = newNode(*"g");
    preorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that it does not work[1] if I put the dereference asterisk on the newNode input instead.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double quotes (`"`) in C denote strings, which become `char *` (pointers).  You want single quotes (`'`) to get char constants.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm curious though why it didn't work when I put the dereference operator in the function input?

Comment: @g_elef:  Making the argument to newNode `const char *data` and then assigning `node->data = *data;` should work fine.  You could also leave out the `const`, though you would then get a warning about it.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

You're are trying to convert from a string (" ") to a char (' '). A string is a  const char * or a char array, or a bunch of characters. Just switch:

```
struct node * root = newNode("a");
```

To

```
struct node * root = newNode('a');
```

and so on for all of your constructors.

Comment: DO NOT cast the malloc return value.  It is worse than useless, as all it does is conceal potential bugs.

Comment: @ChrisDodd It's not wrong, it just shouldn't be done.

Comment: @ThomasJager: it is not illegal or undefined, nor will it generate an error, but it is still wrong.

Comment: A string literal is **not** a pointer to a `const char*`. You can say it is a pointer to `char`. In reality it is an array of type `char`. Also the thing in question here is a string literal not a string.